# How can I find out if a specific plugin is active in WordPress from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am building a dynamic Gutenberg block that needs to render differently according to active plugins. I know there is the PHP function [`is_plugin_active`](https://codex.wordpress.org./Function_Reference/is_plugin_active). Is there an equivalent or a "workaround" to find it out from JavaScript? Or do I need to pass it to JS from PHP?

Comment: You're probably better off localizing `is_plugin_active` data. `wp_localize_script` https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script

Comment: But why? I try to understand, which variables only get set in php, and which are also available in javascript. Because some are, especially variables that concern the gutenberg editor. When typing `wp.` in the javascript console, all the functions are overwhelming.

Comment: If the `wp` JS object doesn't include the data you need (and I don't think it does, why would it include information about active plugins? It's not something everyone would need, I think), either Tony's or the solution I proposed below will do what you need. Don't overthink it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Tony said you could use localization to pass data from PHP into your script.

Another way to go about it is to hook into the [body_class filter hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/body_class) and add custom CSS classes to it if one or more plugins are active:

```
/**
 * Adds additional CSS classes to the body tag if a given plugin is active.
 *
 * @param  array  $classes  An array of CSS classes that will be added to the body tag
 * @return array  $classes  An array of CSS classes that will be added to the body tag
 */
function wp76641_active_plugins_body_classes($classes) {
    include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );

    if ( is_plugin_active('plugin-x-directory/plugin-x-file.php') ) {
        $classes[] = 'plugin-x-is-active';
    }

    return $classes;
}
add_filter('body_class', 'wp76641_active_plugins_body_classes');
```

Then, in your JS you could do something like this:

```
if ( document.body.classList.contains('plugin-x-is-active') ) {
    // Do your thing
}
```